# Avoid '#' from becoming a line break in a flat file

Tags: abap

I have an extract report that creates a flat file to place it in AL11.
Now, one of the description fields has a value that contains `#`.

My data:

```
---------------
Name | Address
---------------
John | Text#123
---------------
```

My flat file:

```
Name#Address#
John#Text#123#
```

When I download the file, I would expect it to be:

```
Name   Address
John   Text#123
```

But what it looks like:

```
Name   Address
John   Text
123
```

How can this be avoided? Is there any unicode that can be translated into a `#` when the file is downloaded?

Comment: In ABAP-based systems, the hash character (`#`) is used in place of [non-printable characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) like "newline" (end of line, line feed) as you experience. I don't get your exact issue, it doesn't look abnormal.

Comment: @SandraRossi Sorry about that. I have edited the question a bit more. You're absolutely right how `#` works. It's just that is there any possibility to make it so that a `#` doesn't act as a newline?

Comment: It's confusing that you continue talking about `#` while the actual character seems to be a newline or horizontal tabulation character. You should first confirm what exact character it is, and if it's a newline character how it can be differentiated from the end of line character, then we can discuss.

Comment: sounds like your source data has linefeed or carriage return char embedded.
Why dont you remove them if you dont want them in the output ?

Comment: It's funny how you are not worried about the #'s that behave like tabs

Comment: @philsoady The user says they need the # in the text they are sending. I am trying to convince them saying it's not feasible but looking for an alternative if it can be rectified.

Comment: Are you using `AL11` to display the data? :O I mean productively?

Comment: User wants the data which includes crlf but doest like how a crlf is output?  What more can one say.

Comment: how do you generate file and how do you download it? it matters. I re-created your scenario and via OPEN DATASET in UTF-8 it works wonderful